# Check a file format in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I not so good in vb. Currently I need to edit this below coding. I need to add one more file format into it. May I know how should I add it? Below is the code.

---

```
If Path.GetExtension(Files(i).FileName).ToString <> ".pptx" Then
    uploadMessage.Text = "Invalid File. Please select "".pptx"" file format to upload."
    uploadMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    fileError_check = 1
    Exit For
ElseIf rdrFileName.HasRows() Then
    fileError_check = 1
    uploadMessage.Text = "File already exists."
    uploadMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    rdrFileName.Close()
    Exit For
End If
```

Thank You.

Comment: If you want to just do something similar to the .pptx part, then easiest is just to add similar code in an elseif.

Comment: can u teach me how should I add it? cause I'm editing previous people code and am not so good in vb.

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on the result of `Path.GetExtension()` is highly unnecessary as the function [already returns a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_GetExtension_System_String_). I don't understand why calling `ToString()` on everything is such a widely spread habit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
'Checking file exist or not & file format
If Path.GetExtension(Files(i).FileName).ToString <> ".pptx" AndAlso Path.GetExtension(Files(i).FileName).ToString <> ".docx"  Then
    uploadMessage.Text = "Invalid File. Please select "".pptx"" or "".docx"" file format to upload."
    uploadMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    fileError_check = 1
    Exit For
ElseIf rdrFileName.HasRows() Then
    fileError_check = 1
    uploadMessage.Text = "File already exists."
    uploadMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    rdrFileName.Close()
    Exit For
End If
```

Comment: An example to use other file format

Comment: this have help me out. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
'Checking file exist or not & file format
If Path.GetExtension(Files(i).FileName).ToString <> ".pptx" Then
    uploadMessage.Text = "Invalid File. Please select "".pptx"" file format to upload."
    uploadMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    fileError_check = 1
    Exit For
ElseIf Path.GetExtension(Files(i).FileName).ToString <> ".docx" Then
    uploadMessage.Text = "Invalid File. Please select "".docx"" file format to upload."
    uploadMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    fileError_check = 1
    Exit For
ElseIf rdrFileName.HasRows() Then
    fileError_check = 1
    uploadMessage.Text = "File already exists."
    uploadMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    rdrFileName.Close()
    Exit For
End If
```

Comment: If Path.GetExtension(Files(i).FileName).ToString **=** ".docx" then it will fail the first `If`, Exit the For, and never get to the ElseIf.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this approach

```
    Dim AcceptedFiles() As String = {".pptx", ".docx"}
    Dim file As New FileInfo(Files(0))
    Try
        If Not AcceptedFiles.Contains(file.Extension) Then
            Throw New ApplicationException(String.Format("Invalid File. only the {0} extensions are accepted", String.Join(",", AcceptedFiles)))
        ElseIf file.Exists Then
            Throw New ApplicationException("File already exists")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        fileError_check = 1
        uploadMessage.Text = ex.Message
        uploadMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red        
    End Try
```

You can then add further extensions to the array as and when required.